# Показывать класс только при скроллинге. Остановка скролла - элемент прячется

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

Есть сайт на wordpress. Не могу сделать такой функционал:

при скроллинге страницы - `div` появляется,

после того как пользователь перестал скроллить страницу - `div` сразу прячется.

Пытался сделать путём добавления класса, класс при скролле появляется, но потом не пропадает... Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() { 
jQuery('.one-page-down').addClass('visible-buttons');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добиться такого поведения можно с помощью `setTimeout`.

Посмотрите пример.

```js
var timeoutId = null;

function hide() {
  $('.one-page-down').removeClass('visible-buttons');
  timeoutId = null;
}
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.one-page-down').addClass('visible-buttons');
  if (timeoutId)
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  timeoutId = setTimeout(hide, 500); // будет скрываться через 500 мс
});
```

```css
.one-page-down {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}

.one-page-down.visible-buttons {
  display: block;
}

.content {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one-page-down">DOWN</div>

<div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

```js
$.fn.scrollStopped = function(callback) {
  var that = this, 
     $this = $(that);
  
  $this.scroll(function(ev) {
    clearTimeout($this.data('scrollTimeout'));
    $this.data('scrollTimeout', setTimeout(callback.bind(that), 250, ev));
    $("#visiblescroll").css({"opacity":"1"});
  });
  
};

$(window).scrollStopped(function(ev){  
  $("#visiblescroll").css({"opacity":"0"});
});
```

```css
#visiblescroll {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #5fba7d;
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 5%;
    left: 5%
    transition: 0.4s;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    justify-content: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 21px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body style="height:3000px">


<div id="visiblescroll"> hello </div>

  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```